# Is it possible to write multiple oracle database tables into one parquet file?

Tags: parquet, parquet-mr

I have a requirement where I want to convert my oracle DB data to parquet. So in my database I have multiple tables for example Employee, Department.
So is it possible to insert the data of both the tables in single parquet file? Or do i need to create separate parquet file for each table?